# Is it possible to declare prototype properties within the js class keyword

Tags: javascript

```
class A {
   // Will be declared on the class instance
   name = “one”;

   // Will be declared on the class constructor 
   static otherName = “two”;

   // Will be on the prototype
   // Is this also possible for properties? (not just for methods)
   greet() {}
}
```

Is it possible to declare a property on the prototype of the class with this syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: You should get used to assigning properties within methods, like `constructor(){ /* in here */ this.name = 'one'; this.constructor.prototype.prop = 'val'; }`.

Answer (score 0):

No, that isn’t part of any fields proposal. You would need to create them separately with `Object.defineProperty`.

```js
Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, 'name', {
   value: 'one',
   configurable: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

```js
class A {
    get x(){
        return 1;
    }
}
console.log(A.prototype.x);
```